# How to Switch an li id='' sprite background using jquery

Tags: jquery, css, image, switch-statement, sprite

How to Switch an li id=''  sprite background using jquery after a click event occurs and switch it back to its original state when clicking in another nav  element  that will switch to another sprite image too.... 
Im using just CSS that changes the background when i hover over the element.. its working fine but what i exactly want is the second sprite image that appear after the click don't change until i click on another nav element..

here is the html code

```
<ul  id="navlist">
<li id="ico1"><a href="#"></a></li>
<li id="ico2"><a href="#"></a></li>
<li id="ico3"><a href="#"></a></li>
<li id="ico4"><a href="#"></a></li>
<li id="ico5"><a href="#"></a></li>
<li id="ico6"><a href="#"></a></li>
<li id="ico7"><a href="#"></a></li>
<li id="ico8"><a href="#"></a></li>
```

The CSS Code:

```
#navlist{position:relative;}
#navlist li{margin:0;padding:0;list-style:none;position:relative;top:0;}
#navlist li, #navlist a{height:40px;display:block;}

#ico1{width:73px;height:40px;background:url(../img/sprite.png) no-repeat -96px 0px;transition: 500ms ease-in-out;}

#ico1:hover{width:96px;height:40px;background:url(../img/sprite.png) no-repeat 0px 0px;transition: 500ms ease-in-out;}
```

.... etc

Here is the example : http://jsfiddle.net/facemoi/nvQRf/

Comment: CSS doesn't handle click state. Your best bet is to use JavaScript to add/remove an `active` class to the clicked nav and use that class to set your background properties.

Answer (score 2):

Let's say you have a common class that all list items inherit:

```
.ico{
   background: url(images/sprite.jpg);
}
```

Now create classes for each item and for hover/active state:

```
.ico1{
   background-position: 0 12px;
}

.ico1:hover{
   background-position: 0 24px;
}

.ico1.active{
   background-position: 0 32px;
}

...
```

And with jQuery you would only toggle the `active` class on click

```
$('li').click(function(){

  // remove active class for all other list items
  $(this).parents('ul').find('li').not(this).removeClass('active');

  // add active class on this item
  $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

([a demo](http://jsfiddle.net/smB7b/))

This actually *is* possible without javascript, but you would need to add hidden radio buttons in your markup and make the icons labels

Comment: could simplify to `$('li.active').removeClass('active');`